# using derived table in mysql

Tags: mysql

There are two tables. P(pno,pname,color) and sp(sno,pno,qty) and s(sno,sname)
I want to get the most supplied pname and its total supplied quantity.
I wrote query using derived table like

```
select pno,totalqty 
from (select p.pno, sum(quality) as totalqty 
      from p,sp 
      where p.pno=sp.pno  
      group by p.pno
     )d 
where totalqty = (select max(totalqty) 
                  from (select p.pno, sum(quality) as totalqty  
                        from p,sp 
                        where p.pno=sp.pno 
                        group by p.pno
                       )d
                 );
```

I have to repeat the expressions that find the total number of quantity of each part. I can not reuse derived name ( I used d). is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in MySQL, but you can put it into a temporary table instead, use a variable to store the max() and then select from it a second time. Putting it into one query would need cloning the temp table because it can be used only once in one query (unfortunate but deep limitation which was not yet been lifted afaik). - https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/64556